My java program running well only with IDE env, not built jar
I made some simple java httpserver app for local
When I tested my app on IDE (like eclipse, STS) => It works that I expected
But When I tested my app that built with maven => Not working well
My code:
package nac.NACPlasticCardPrintWithDTC1250eServer;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class ServerRunner {
    HttpServer hs;
    final int PORT = 3194;
    static NACDomain[] domains = {NACDomain.L, NACDomain.D, NACDomain.S, NACDomain.P};
    
    ServerRunner() {
        try {
            hs = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(PORT), 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        hs.createContext("/print", new PrintHandler());
        hs.setExecutor(null);
    }
    void Start() {
        hs.start();
    }
    void Kill() {
        hs.stop(1);
    }
}

class PrintHandler implements HttpHandler {
    final String RES = "OK";
    final String FORB = "Forbidden";
    OutputStream os;
    
    boolean DomainCheck(String d) {
        return Arrays.stream(ServerRunner.domains).anyMatch(item -> item.get().equals(d));
    }
    void OptionsHandle(HttpExchange e, String o) throws IOException {
        if(this.DomainCheck(o)) {
            e.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", o);
            e.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS");
            e.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
            e.sendResponseHeaders(204, -1);
        } else {
            e.sendResponseHeaders(403, FORB.getBytes().length);
        }
    }
    private byte[] readFully(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[16384];
        while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }
        return buffer.toByteArray();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Map<String, String> bodyToMap(InputStream requestBody) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String body = new String(readFully(requestBody), "UTF-8");
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        return om.readValue(body, Map.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        String m = exchange.getRequestMethod();
        String origin = exchange.getRequestHeaders().getFirst("Origin");
        int code = 200;
        String msg = RES;
        // Preflight
        if(m.equals("OPTIONS")) {
            this.OptionsHandle(exchange, origin);
            return;
        }
        // Validate
        if(this.DomainCheck(origin)) exchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        else {
            code = 403;
            msg = FORB;
        }
        System.out.println("Before init om");
        try {
            ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
            System.out.println("After init om");
            // Work
            Map<String, String> param = bodyToMap(exchange.getRequestBody());
//          PrintCard pc = new PrintCard();
//          pc.Print(param.get("up"), param.get("down"));
            // Return
            String json = "{\"result\": \"" + msg + "\"}";
            byte[] res = json.getBytes();
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(code, res.length);
            os = exchange.getResponseBody();
            os.write(res);
            os.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No trace?");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

The problem is ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
In built jar, System print only "Before init om", not "After init om"
So after that code never has reach
Also catch block line has not reached as well
My pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>nac</groupId>
  <artifactId>NACPlasticCardPrintWithDTC1250eServer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>at.stderr</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
  </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                      <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                      <mainClass>nac.NACPlasticCardPrintWithDTC1250eServer.CardPrintServerApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                  <mainClass>nac.NACPlasticCardPrintWithDTC1250eServer.CardPrintServerApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <local.lib>${basedir}/lib</local.lib>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>impl.Fargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>FargoJavaAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${local.lib}/FargoJavaAPI.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${local.lib}/jna.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>


Running built jar screenshot:

What is reason that program works only on IDE?

Try changing catch(Exception e) to catch(Throwable e)
